# C# Equivalent to overwriting __dict__ in class

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

In Python, we can directly declare the attributes of a class by using **slots** which saves memory (and makes accessing class attributes faster I think).

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = "foo", "bar"
    # rest of code
```

So question is: is there an equivalent to this in C# to optimize programs?

Comment: C# class definitions *already* define a fixed set of "slots", known in C# as [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). There is nothing left for C# (a statically-typed language) to optimize vs Python (a dynamically-typed language).

Answer (score 0):

Alas, No there isn't. But When you write a standard class definition, it will be optimised by the compiler.